# Finding a substring (from list of strings) in a string column and add as a new column in Dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe, substring

I have the following dataframe (`df`) containing strings in the "text" column:

| text | sth |
| --- | --- |
| abdcdtext1wrew | ... |
| qwerqdtext2cvufu | ... |
| iuotext3tvbv | ... |
| iuotvbvewre | ... |

I also have a **Series** (`df_look_for`) contains the strings I will be looking for:

| look_for |
| --- |
| text1 |
| text2 |
| text3 |

My goal is to check the "**text**" column whether it contains one of the strings in the "**look_for**" column. If it contains I want to add the found string as a new column in `df`. For example:

| text | sth | found_str |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abdcdtext1wrew | ... | text1 |
| qwerqdtext2cvufu | ... | text2 |
| iuotext3tvbv | ... | text3 |
| iuotvbvewre | ... | `NaN` |

So far I am trying to use `str.contains()` but hasn't succeed yet.

Any help would appreciate it!

Comment: Your expected output does not match your `df`. There is a missing row in this one.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a *listcomp* with [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to avoid nested lists.

```
lookfor = df_look_for["look_for"]
​
df["found_str"] = [next((a for a in lookfor if a in b), None) for b in df["text"]]
```

Output :

```
print(df)
​
               text  sth found_str
0    abdcdtext1wrew  ...     text1
1  qwerqdtext2cvufu  ...     text2
2      iuotext3tvbv  ...     text3
3       iuotvbvewre  ...      None
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Can you explain what you mean by "avoid nested lists"? `next()` function is not clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove `next` and re-write the _listcomp_ and you'll see that the values in the column `found_str` will be enclosed between square brackets. For example, in the first row, you'll get `[text1]` (_a list_) instead of `text1` (_a string_).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) together with [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)

```py
df_look = pd.Series(['text1', 'text2', 'text3'])
df['found_str'] = list(map(lambda x: next((y for y in df_look if y in x), 'NaN'), df['text']))
print(df)
```

You could also use `re` together with [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```py
import re

df_look = pd.Series(['text1', 'text2', 'text3'])
pattern = '|'.join(df_look.tolist())

df['found_str'] = df['text'].str.extract(f'({pattern})', expand=False)
df.fillna(value='NaN', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

---

```
               text  sth found_str
0    abdcdtext1wrew  ...     text1
1  qwerqdtext2cvufu  ...     text2
2      iuotext3tvbv  ...     text3
3       iuotvbvewre  ...       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method. This will give list of all found strs:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'text': ['asdtext1', 'sdkjfhtext2sdf', 'dsfds']}
l = {'look_for': ['text1', 'text2']}

look_for_df = pd.DataFrame(data=l)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["found_str"] = df['text'].apply(lambda text: [search_word for search_word in look_for_df['look_for'] if search_word in text])
```

[image]